# Zend Framework Application deployment online

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zend framework I have built an application with SQL and everything store in a folder in my Xampp.  Now that I am finish what steps do I need to put this online for users to use and see?

I have a specified URL that I am suppose to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for Zend Framework, if everything has been put into the suggested places (a default config), the steps would probably be:

1. Check database access
2. Check if .htaccess is in place
3. Check if you VirtualHost is pointed to the public folder
4. Check if proper environment variable is passed to the application
5. Check if log/tmp folders are writeable

These should be the general steps. Other than this, it gets too application specific to try to guess.